# How to add numbers together instead of increasing the value ?Like joining

Tags: c++

I want to concatenate two integers, that is not adding their values, but join them.

For example:

```
int a=2,b;
cin>>b;
a=a+3;
```

`a` should be something like `23` instead of `5`.

How can I do that?

Comment: The magic word you're probably looking for is **concatenation**. Don't use "add" in the context of numbers when you don't really mean numerical addition ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method would be to multiply the number by 10 and then add the new integer.

Edit: Other answers were more accurate.  In the case where a number can be above 10 you will need to either treat them as strings and then convert back to int (itoa on the c_str()). If you want to keep them as int, you will need to know which power of 10 contains your new value and multiply the number by this power of 10 to make enough room for the new number.

Comment: Unless the new number is greater than 9.

Comment: Indeed, I was simply going with the examples.  Otherwise, handling the numbers as string and then converting them to int (int value = atoi(theString.c_str());) would be the way to go

Comment: Base 10 logarithms and a `floor` function will be your friends in that situation. Nonetheless, the string conversion approaches will avoid integer overflow issues when very large numbers are involved. Either that, or use some kind of bignum to store the result.

Answer (score 4):

Just because they look like integers, doesn't mean they're integers. In your case, you're trying to perform string operations on integers. What you really want is to use `std::string`:

```
std::string a("2");
std::string b;
std::cin >> b;
a += b;
```

If you then want to use the result as an `int`, you can use `std::stoi(a)` in C++11. In C++03, you can do:

```
std::stringstream ss(a);
int value;
ss >> value;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you what you want.

```
std::stringstream s;
s << 1 << 2 << 3;
int out;
s >> out;
std::cerr << out << std::endl;
```

[The String Formatters of Manor](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm) Farm by Herb Sutter is worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to convert the numbers into strings, simply multiply the previous value by 10:

a = a*10 + b;

Answer (score 0):

look at this again:

```
int a=2,b;
cin>>b;
a=a+3;
```

how you want to a be 23?
your b is completly ignored in your add statement, you have `a=2`, so `a+3` is really 2+3, so 2+3 if i remember math is around 5.

Answer (score 0):

In C, You can  use the *int to alphabet* function `itoa(int1,str1,10)`.

Code to concatenate two integers as strings:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  int int1,int2;
  char *str1,*str2;
  str1 = new char[1];
  str2 = new char[1];
  string str;

  cout<<"concatenate two integers as strings \n";
  cout<<"Enter first number > ";
  cin>>int1;

  cout<<"Enter second number > ";
  cin>>int2;

  str=string(itoa(int1,str1,10)) + string(itoa(int2,str2,10));;

  cout<<"\n "<<str <<"\n";


  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

   return 0;
```

}

output:

```
concatenate two integers as strings
Enter first number > 2
Enter second number > 3

 23

Press any key to continue
```